# Use Ziproxy with OpenVPN

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, proxy, openvpn

I for the life of me cannot figure out how to chain the internet connection from OpenVPN to Ziproxy. I already am able to set up a working OpenVPN and Ziproxy installation separate of each other, but iOS doesn't allow a proxy over cellular.

In the end I will need 2 instances of OpenVPN. One that compresses with Ziproxy, and one that does not. I could probably do that part myself, but any help is more than appreciated

Oh, and the server is Ubuntu Trusty

Answer (score 0):

Route with IP tables from OpenVPN network port 80 to 8080

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Comment: Could you explain why you think this will help the OP?